# Is there a way to alter values in a column of a dataframe that is in a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary of dataframes:

```
In[4]: df_dict
Out[4]:

1:     A   B   C   D
   0  68   0  98  83
   1  10  71  36  69
   2  49  57  59  40
   3  54  28  64  37
   4  70  58  91  29

2:     A   B   C   D
   0  17  69  59   7
   1  79  66  72  53
   2  81  37  26  34
   3   0  63  80  15
   4  20  55  64  86

3:     A   B   C   D
   0  14  79  91  14
   1  89  86  57  59
   2  42  18   7  51
   3  22  85  63  35
   4  10  12  46  92
```

If I want to add the string "JAN" to every value in column B in each dataframe of the dictionary, how would I do that? For example for the dataframe with key == 1, I would want the values in column B to be [0JAN, 71JAN, 57JAN, 28JAN, 58JAN] and I would want that for each column B in the dictionary. Assume the current values of column B are already formatted as strings.

Comment: `for k, v in df_dict.items(): v['B'] = v['B'].astype(str) + 'JAN'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-create the dictionary:

```
df_dict = {k: df.assign(df['B'].astype(str) + 'JAN') for k, df in df_dict.items()}
```

---

Alternatively, assign in-place, this is slightly cheaper:

```
for df in df_dict.values():
    df['B'] = df['B'].astype('str') + 'JAN'
```

Or,

```
# Iterate over the items, @jpp
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[k]['B'] = v['B'].astype('str') + 'JAN'
```